# UpdateJoystickValue is not working in Windows-SDK

Tags: dji-sdk

I tried to control the drone with the virtual remote controller. But nothing happens (no Exception is thrown, the drone's (DJI Phantom 4 V2 Pro) position does not change). As mentioned in the API: the drone is flying while I send the UpdateJoystick command.

E.g. :for changing the drones altitude I use the following code:

`DJISDKManager.Instance.VirtualRemoteController.UpdateJoystickValue(0.5f, 0.0f 0.0f 0.0f);`

Answer (score 1):

The virtual remote controller is available when SDK is connected to the aircraft through WiFi and without a physical remote controller. So currently only mavic air support this function.

Comment: Maybe you know it: will virtual sticks be supported in the future for physical remote controller connection?